# How to sum amount by source ID only for current month with MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have this table in MySQL

```
source amount for_date
1        100   2019-01-15
1        200   2019-01-16
1        200   2019-02-16
2        350   2019-02-14

SELECT SUM(amount) amountSum FROM Flow WHERE source='1' GROUP BY month(for_date)
```

This MySQL query work, but I want to get only the current month, not the month before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the month with `where` condition

**Month only**

```
SELECT SUM(amount) amountSum FROM Flow WHERE source='1' AND month(for_date)=month(now()) GROUP BY month(for_date)
```

**With year**

```
 SELECT SUM(amount) amountSum FROM Flow WHERE source='1' AND month(for_date)=month(now()) AND year(for_date)=year(now()) GROUP BY month(for_date)
```

Comment: what is the use of group by here??

Comment: This work perfect for me. I use in php function. Thank you.

Comment: @prasanth Tell me in this case, again for the current month
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN source='21' THEN amount WHEN source='22' then +amount ELSE 0 END ) sumDel FROM Flow GROUP BY month(for_date)

Comment: @prasanth Here i want to sum only current month.
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN source='21' THEN amount WHEN source='22' then +amount ELSE 0 END ) sumDel FROM Flow GROUP BY month(for_date)

Comment: @Martin use with where condition `month(for_date)=month(now()) AND year(for_date)=year(now())` .it will show only this month

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining the current month as the month of today's date, then you don't even need to aggregate here:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) amountSum
FROM Flow
WHERE
    source = '1' AND
    DATE_FORMAT(for_date, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m');
```

If you are instead defining the current month as whatever happens to be the latest month in your table, then we can use `LIMIT` with your current query:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) amountSum
FROM Flow
WHERE source = '1'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(for_date , '%Y-%m')
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(for_date , '%Y-%m') DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Can this be written to use an index?

Comment: Not of which I know unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I would add two date parameters to the query like so:

```
SELECT amount FROM table WHERE for_date>='2019-01-01' AND for_date<='2019-01-31'
```

Comment: What happens when the OP adds new data to the table from February 2019?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT SUM(amount) amountSum FROM Flow WHERE source='1' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(for_date, "%m-%y")
```

This will sum and group by the month/year in case that your database grows and have multiple years.

Comment: this query will give current month... but it will group all the months and years...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     SELECT SUM(amount) FROM Flow WHERE source='1' AND MONTH(for_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(for_date)=YEAR(CURRENT_DATE());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(amount) amountSum FROM Flow WHERE source='1' and DATE_FORMAT(for_date,'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%Y-%m')
```

what is the use of group by? if you only want the current month? why are you using group by?
run the above query there is no use of group by...